# Conditional Formatting to allow insert but not delete

Tags: insert, formatting, conditional-statements, infopath

In infopath I would like to insert a row into a repeating section without letting the user delete a row (because there is only one row). How can I do this if it is possible through conditional formatting or through code?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the user from doing anything to the repeating row, through the properties of the repearting row.  you can diable user interaction completely and add the rows programatically or only allow the user to add the row, by turning off the menu items allowed, though I don't think that it removes the ability to select a row and the pressing delete button.

Comment: Infopath is getting an error when the only repeating section is deleted, so I want to prevent users from only deleting. Theres nothing under properties....

Comment: @kperson Under the repeating section properties select "Customize Commands...". This will let you turn off specific repeating row options. 

Like Nathan mentioned, users will still be able to manually delete the row by selecting it and hitting the delete key.